# Codeigniter Submit Ajax Result Via Button to Datatable Not Working

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm currently using Codeigniter and using Ajax to post my search result through the server and result the result and display on my responsive datatable. However the result was not added into my datatable and i even try to add it with .append but it just added below my table and the search function on datatable is not searching it and it still show "No data available in table".

Here are my View :

```
<div id="reporting" class="container">
  <h3 class="section-title">Export Time Location Panel</h3>
  <form id = "search">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-group">
            <h5>Date/ Time</h5>
              <input type="datetime-local" name="datetime" id = "datetime">
            <?php echo form_error('datetime'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm</button>
  </form><br/>
         <table class="table table-bordered table-light" >
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <td class="id">ID</td>
        <td class="na">NA Name</td>
        <td class="centre">Centre Name</td>
        <td class="login">Date & Time</td>
        <td class="lat">Latitude</td>
        <td class="long">Longtitude</td>
        <td class="accuracy">Accuracy</td>
        <td class="place">Location Name</td>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var tbl = $('.table').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            "order": [[0, "desc"]]
        })

         $( "#search" ).submit(function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         var value  = $("#datetime").val();
             $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'<?php echo base_url(); ?>location/search_record',
                    data:{'datetime':value},
                    success:function(data){
                        $('.table').append(data);
                    }
                });

        });
    } );
</script>
```

Here are my Model :

```
    public function search_record(){ //Display Record at View Page
    $this->load->model('location_model');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        echo '
  <tr>
        <td class="id">ID</td>
        <td class="na">NA Name</td>
        <td class="centre">Centre Name</td>
        <td class="login">Date & Time</td>
        <td class="lat">Latitude</td>
        <td class="long">Longtitude</td>
        <td class="accuracy">Accuracy</td>
        <td class="place">Location Name</td>
      </tr>

        ';

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add data to table body by

```
success:function(data){ tbl.rows.add($(data)).draw(); }
```

Please check this link

https://jsfiddle.net/kuLcqwav/3/

https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html

Comment: i did try the append, but it just adding at the bottom of the datatable instead of the table inside it self, the link using different way to draw right

Comment: Try this 

 success:function(data){
tbl.rows.add($(data)).draw();
                    }

Comment: why does if i use to add 3 more row from the echo, the datatable prompted error?

Comment: i add like this

  <tr>
   <td >2</td>
   <td >NA Name</td>
   <td >Centre Name</td>
   <td >Date & Time</td>
   <td >Latitude</td>
   <td >Longtitude</td>
   <td >Accuracy</td>
   <td >Location Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td >3</td>
   <td >NA Name</td>
   <td >Centre Name</td>
   <td >Date & Time</td>
   <td >Latitude</td>
   <td >Longtitude</td>
   <td >Accuracy</td>
   <td >Location Name</td>
  </tr>

Comment: how if i wanted to return multiple row in the model and append into the datatable?

Comment: Try This code :

data = data.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, '');
data = data.replace(/\\r\\n/gm, '');

var expr = "</tr>\\s*<tr";
var regEx = new RegExp(expr, "gm");
var newRows = data.replace(regEx, "</tr><tr");                        
tbl.rows.add($(newRows)).draw();

Comment: you cannot directly append data into a jquery datatable. use jquery datatable javascript api.